# 301 redirect from subdomain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to set up a 301 redirect from a subdomain to a subfolder, but nothing I do seems to work. The goal is to set up a redirect from the subdomain "learn", to a subdirectory "learn".

learn.site-name.com -> site-name.com/learn

I have not been able to successfully set this up on our (kinsta) staging site. learn.site-name.com just goes straight to site-name.com.

What am I doing wrong??

Here is the .htaccess (site name obscured for client's privacy):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 12M
php_value post_max_size 13M

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^learn\.XXXX.kinsta\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.kinsta.com/learn/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @anubhava it just does nothing - learn.XXXX.com goes right to XXXX.com (I will update my post with what happens, thank you for reminding me)

Comment: ok can you show `VirtualHost` config for `learn.XXXX.com` and `XXXX.com` ?

Comment: "learn.site-name.com just goes straight to site-name.com" - What is the HTTP status code of the redirect? If you remove the directives in `.htaccess`, do you still see the redirect? (NB: 301 redirects are cached, so you will need to ensure your browser cache is cleared.)